# Custom type in TypeScript for ID that is not in the DB

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am currently building a quite big web-application with typescript as its backend. I have a function that adds a user to my database:

```
function doSomethingWithUser(id: ValidUserId, ...someOtherInformation: any[]): boolean {
    // doing the db stuff
    return true
}
```

but i want the `id` parameter to have its own type called `NewUserId` which should only be used for strings that contain user ids that are currently not in the database.
I want to have this feature, because currently i always have to remember to check if the id does not already exist in the db, with the own type typescript would remind me to check for that, because there would be a type conflict.

I tried using a custom typeguard by typescript:

```
type ValidUserId = string & {"ValidUserId": {}}
function isValidUserId(id: string): id is ValidUserId {
    // check if there is no user with the id in the database
    return numberOfUsersWithThisId == 0
}
```

This would work, but the problem is, that i obviously would need an async function for the typeguard to do some db stuff, but typescript does not allow for async type guards. Is there a good replacement for this?

Comment: You say "this would work" but it wouldn't, even if you could make `stringIsNewUserId` asynchronous.  `NewUserId` is just an alias for `string` and all strings will be perceived as `NewUserId` whether you call a type guard function or not; presumably you want `NewUserId` to be a *nominal type* as discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  Do you want to make that change to the question so people can focus on the async aspect?

Comment: Even with that change I'm confused about the use case. TS types aren't state dependent; if a string `s` is a `NewUserId` and you call `addUserToDb(s)`, presumably afterward *`s` should no longer be a valid `NewUserId`* because it's in the database.  But the type of `s` will always and forever be a `NewUserId`, so `addUserToDb(s); addUserToDb(s);` would be unavoidably allowed no matter what.  TS doesn't have a [substructural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system) so it can't easily represent "ownership" of `s` the way you would need to.

Comment: @jcalz oh, you are right, edited that, thx.
But the second thing would not be a problem in my case, because the `addUserToDb` function is only called on an API call and the `NewUserId` `s` is not going to be used after that anymore

Comment: It's pretty distracting, though.  Maybe you could change the example so that there's no sense in which simply using the value would cause it no longer to be valid?  Like, for example, [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkOxJW), where the aysnc check is "is this a valid id" and you only want your other function to accept a valid id, but the other function does not make the valid id invalid anymore.

Comment: And then my suggestion would be to replace the type guard with a plain async function that returns a valid id or undefined, and you'd use it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvaMrm).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Oh, a function simply returning a ValidUserId is actually a good idea, I guess I just got caught up in the typescript feature of custom type guards. I am going to use that. Could you write that in an answer instead of an comment, so I can approve your answer?

Comment: Sure I’ll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, there is currently no support for *asynchronous* [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) returning something like `Promise<id is ValidUserId>`.  There's an open feature request for such support at [microsoft/TypeScript#37681](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681), but it's not clear when or even if it will be implemented.  For now you just have to work around it.

---

Probably the most direct workaround is to give up on custom type guards and just return a value which is either of the narrowed type (if the type guard function would have returned `true`) or `undefined` (if the type guard function would have returned `false`), like this:

```
declare function toValidUserId(id: string): Promise<ValidUserId | undefined>;
```

implemented however you need to implement it:

```
async function toValidUserId(id: string): Promise<ValidUserId | undefined> {
    const isValid = await Math.random() < 0.5; // <-- do a real check here
    return isValid ? (id as ValidUserId) : undefined;
}
```

keeping in mind that you'll need some kind of [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that `id` is an acceptable instance of a [branded primitive type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).

Anyway, now you'd use the return value from `toValidUserId()` instead of re-using its argument:

```
async function foo() {
    const id = "abcde";
    const validatedUserId = await toValidUserId(id);
    if (validatedUserId) {
        // is valid
        doSomethingWithUser(validatedUserId); // okay
    } else {
        // is not valid
        console.log(id + " isn't a valid id!");
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TCrHKBsboNQa8PeSOHPy01iylGjTnwFoEIq8a7weY67zQovF4xmSw2OyOZy+VzZrC5vVs0t6cXISCNiSwVD4F3Fktc8uV6u1w3G66NoPu6qwIKoPT0TUAak4mNwtAA5CHkGGVZjMABCDipsd3B4PIA)